# Determine whether the set of vectors Span the vector space $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine whether the set of vectors $\{ (2,-3,1), (4,1,1), (0,-7,1) \}$ span the vector space $\mathbb {R^3}$ ?

Comment: Do you know about determinants?

Comment: yes i know about determinants.

Comment: i have tried row echelon form to reduce it into matrix to find value of c1, c2, c3, in terms of x1, x2 and x3

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  $2(2,-3,1)-(4,1,1)=(0,-7,1).$

---

Alternatively, if the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Alternative_method_using_determinants) of the matrix with the vectors as rows or columns is $0$,

then they do not span $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: thanks, this means a lot to me, but i have to prove this by using row echelon form, can u help plz?

Comment: @JazimT that is already addressed in this answer with the first hint.

Answer (score 0):

Stack the vectors vertically and reduce the matrix to the echelon form (through row-wise elementary transformations only) as follows:
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -3 & 1 \\
4 & 1  & 1 \\
0 & -7 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \to 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -3 & 1 \\
0 & 7  & -1 \\
0 & -7 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \to
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -3 & 1 \\
0 & 7  & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Can you identify what transformation I used in each step and reach the conclusion?

Comment: yes i can identify the transformation , but i can't reach the proper conclusion.

Comment: The last row is $(0, 0, 0)$, so they cannot span $\mathbb{R}^3$.